# Does IntelliJ require an installed JDK?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was trying to run IntelliJ on my laptop. I don't have a JDK file but I do have a JRE file. Can I run IntelliJ on my windows laptop with JRE and without JDK? For the information, I have windows 11 version.
Thank you

Comment: No. You can't compile Java code without a Java compiler. Also, as of Java 11, there isn't an official JRE anymore.

Comment: You should be able to download a JDK under Preferences

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I do not know what you mean by "official" JRE. Several JDK venders offer a "JRE" edition of their products that omit the compiler-related tooling: Azul Systems, BellSoft, SAP, Adoptium, and more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking on the documentation of IntelliJ on [how to change the runtime](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html) it says:

> By default, IntelliJ IDEA uses JetBrains Runtime (a fork of OpenJDK), which is included with the IDE.

So it should be possible to start IntelliJ without an additional installed JDK even without a separate installed JRE.

However, in order to compile and execute new written Java programs you must have a compiler, which is part of the Java Development Kit (JDK). Otherwise, you cannot compile and execute your written Java programs with IntelliJ.

Without an installed JDK you will most likely only be able to use IntelliJ has an enhanced text editor, but not as a fully integrated development environment.

Comment: It doesn't need installed separately. It [comes with its own](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)